# MIPS stack pointer

Tags: c, mips

Feeling a little silly here, trying to work out what this line is doing:

```
addiu   sp,sp,-24
```

I understand that it is setting the stack pointer, my confusion is the `addiu` part. It's adding the UNSIGNED `-24` to the stack pointer, and storing it back in the stack pointer.

Does `sp` take the value of the 16 bit -24(`FFE8`) (the "immediate" value of the `addiu` operation is 16 bits wide) or does it extend the sign to the full 32 bits?

Also, is `sp=0` prior to this instruction? It is the first instruction in a trivial piece of c code.

I'm implementing a MIPS core as a personal project, and this has me a little stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The addiu instruction includes a 16-bit immediate operand. When the ALU executes the instruction, the immediate operand is sign-extended to 32 bits. If two's complement overflow occurs during the addition, it is ignored.

```
addiu   d,s,const        # $d <—— s + const. 
                         # Const is 16-bit two's comp. sign-extended to 32 bits
                         # when the addition is done. No overflow trap.
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. It looks like you are quoting a document here, do you have a link? The one I'm using is: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2015sp/MIPS_Vol2.pdf

Comment: @ZackNewsham It from some slides of a course I attened to some time ago. Maybe extrapolated from the pdf you linked.

Answer (score 1):

### Arithmetic Instructions

MIPS supports the four basic arithmetic operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication, and
division.

**Addition Instructions**: The basic addition instruction

```
 add Rdest,Rsrc1,Rsrc2
```

adds contents of `Rsrc1` and `Rsrc2`  and stores the result in `Rdest`. The numbers are treated as signed integers. In case of an overflow, an overflow exception is generated. `addu` can be used if no overflow exception is needed.

The second operand can be specified as an `immediate 16-bit number`. The format is:

```
 addi Rdest,Rsrc1,imm
```

The `16-bit` value is `sign-extended to 32 bits` and added to the contents of `Rsrc1`. As in the add instruction, an overflow exception is generated. As in add, we can use `addiu` if an overflow exception is not needed.

### Stack Implementation

The MIPS does not explicitly support stack operations. In contrast, it
provides instructions such as push and pop to facilitate stack operations. In addition, there is a special stack pointer register `sp` that keeps the top-of-stack information. In the MIPS, a register plays the role of the stack pointer. We have to manipulate this register to implement the stack.

For example, the stack grows downward (i.e., as we push items onto the stack, the address de- creases). Thus, when reserving space on the stack for pushing values, we have to decrease the `sp`  value. Thus, the relative value of the stack pointer at the beginning of execution could be taken as zero.

For example, to push registers `a0` and `ra`, we have to reserve eight bytes of stack space and use `sw` to push the values as shown below:

```
sub $sp,$sp,8 # reserve 8 bytes of stack
sw $a0,0($sp) # save registers
sw $ra,4($sp)
```

This sequence is typically used at the beginning of a procedure to save registers. To restore these registers before returning from the procedure, we can use the following sequence:

```
lw $a0,0($sp) # restore the two registers
lw $ra,4($sp)
addu $sp,$sp,8 # clear 8 bytes of stack
```

So, the answer to your first question:

> The `16-bit` value is `sign-extended to 32 bits` and added to the contents of `Rsrc1`.

and to your second question:

> Thus, the relative value of the stack pointer at the beginning of execution could be taken as zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it seems to be targeted to `addi` not `addiu` I am aware that the sign is extended in `addi` as makes sense. My question was how it affects `addiu`

Comment: @Zack Newsham You are welcome :), `addiu` is a special case of `addi`, when no overflow exception is needed and the same properties apply.